# Place inputs vertically one after each other with CSS

Tags: html, css, input

I have some inputs, and I want them to be placed vertically one after other, I mean the 1st to be in the 1st line, the 2nd to be in the 2nd line and so on.

To do that, I used HTML like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Team1</legend>
    <label for="player1">Player1</label>
    <input type="number" name="player1"><br/>
    <label for="player2">Player2</label>
    <input type="number" name="player2"><br/>
</fieldset>
```

where you can see I used `br`, yeah I know shame of me!

So, how to do that with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wrap the `label` and `input` inside a `div`. `div` being a block level element tends to take up the available width. Make use of absolute positioning to align the legend to the right. `background: #fff` will make sure it has an overlap effect.

```css
fieldset {
  position: relative;
}
legend {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Team1</legend>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="player1">Player1</label>
    <input type="number" name="player1">
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="player2">Player2</label>
    <input type="number" name="player2">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Yeah, right! Thanks. Manoj can ask you if I could move the Team1 legend to the right? I tried `float:right`, but that did not work nicely.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the markup? :) Edited the code.

Comment: Well I placed it underneath the inputs, but that didn't help. But probably you didn't mean that... Hmm..

Comment: Hey, sorry I thought you were asking about the input fields. I have edited the code to float the legend to right.

Comment: Now your answer uses a class that is not displayed in the CSS. Also, what if Player2 becomes Player2345? The inputs are not vertically aligned with regards to them!

Comment: That is normal behavior, you will need to wrap the label inside a width div, so that the input elements are lined up vertically.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried, but the label was leaving it's position then. I may have to ask another question, right?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you asking a new question. Already this is a variation from the question regarding the legend :)

Comment: I agree, here you go future readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234991/vertically-align-inputs-with-each-other

Answer (score 3):

You could do this only with CSS:

```
input + label:before {
  content: '\A';      /* unicode for line-breaks */
  white-space: pre;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bo0dL0wk/

From Lea Verou's book: "CSS Secrets: Better Solutions to everyday Webdesign problems"

Comment: I like this answer a lot.

Comment: What if Player2 becomes Player2345? The inputs are not vertically aligned with regards to them!

Answer (score 1):

Labels can be wrapped around inputs and via CSS set to block. I'm a fan of using as less html elements as sanely possible. Less html is easier to understand. This could use a little tweaking, but it's to show as an example:

```css
label{ display: block; }
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Team1</legend>
    <label>
        Player1 <input type="number" name="player1" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Player2 <input type="number" name="player2" /> 
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Martijin that was exactly the answer (before edits) of Manoj, but thanks, I will give you an upvote for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Float both the `label` and the `input` left.  Then `clear` the previous float on the `label`:

```css
label, input {
  float: left;
}

label {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Team1</legend>
  <label for="player1">Player1</label>
  <input type="number" name="player1">
  <label for="player2">Player2</label>
  <input type="number" name="player2">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: An upvote for showing an alternative approach that works well too, thanks Rick!