# Vertically align inputs with each other

Tags: html, css, input

I have two inputs, but the pre-displayed labels have different length, causing the inputs not to start from the same position (vertically speaking). How to achieve that?

Some of my attempts are:

```
input {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

input {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Please notice that `display: block;` will make the label and input lose their initial corresponding positions!

My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/bo0dL0wk/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**CSS table layout**](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero). The parent element acts as a table row and the child elements as table cells.

```css
.input-container {
  display: table-row;
}
.input-container * {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Team1</legend>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="player1">Player1</label>
    <input type="number" name="player1">
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="player2">Player2345</label>
    <input type="number" name="player2">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```